# Configure tests and coverage to run at setup

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, coverage.py

I'm supposed to configure a python package with tests and coverage.

Now, I can successfully run tests (with nosetest) and coverage (through coverage.py), but I'm a little confused on how to make them run automatically, when the package is installed or updated.

I've searched online and I edited my setup.py file so it looks something like this:

```
    ...
    test_suite='nose.collector',
    setup_requires=['nose>=1.0','coverage>=1.0'],
    tests_require=['nose'],
    ...
```

My confusion is such that I cannot even understand if this is *enough* to make it work. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have never heard of a Python package that runs tests when it is installed.  Don't do that.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood, that's exactly what my senior teammate wants to do. Can't ignore him.

Comment: I understand you are in a tough position then.  Your senior teammate is trying to do something that isn't usually done. You will have a difficult time of it.  Try to explain the Python idioms and culture to him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are after a [Continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) solution like [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) (or any other) that installs and runs your package against the test suite in every branch (including master).

You can take a look in GitHub at how other open source projects are doing it, for example [aiohttp](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp):

aiohttp is running their CI pipeline in Travis CI:

- The configuration is at [.travis.yml](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/.travis.yml)
- As you can see there, it is
  executing the test suite through the [Makefile](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/Makefile)

Another project doing something similar is [flask](https://github.com/pallets/flask)

Comment: Yes, I need to set up my project for CI - however I won't be the one setting CI up, a senior team member wants to do it. I'm looking up your solution in the meantime